# how to reset score after hold down for 0.3 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to make where if you hold down for 3 seconds your score resets. and i tryed an if statement and that didnt work cause it was unity so i would like help i am a new coder and i dont know much.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int clicks = 0;
    public TMP_Text clickText;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        clickText.text = "Clicks: " + clicks;
    }

    public void Click() {
        clicks++;
    }
}
```

Comment: please help im trying to make a unity game

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Input.GetKey()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) this will help you to check when the key is held down.
Add that in your `Update()` method.